# Which Secure Software Development Practices do you Employ?

Tags: cryptography, static-analysis, security

I work on a project known as the Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) project at Microsoft (http://microsoft.com/sdl) - in short it's a set of practices that must be used by product groups before they ship products to help improve security.

Over the last couple of years, we have published a great deal of SDL documentation, as customers ask for more information about what we're doing.

But what I'd like to know is:

1. What are you doing within your organization to help improve the security of your product?
2. What works? What doesn't work?
3. How did you get management to agree to this work?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a good question by a good guy. Microsoft's software is deployed to a huge amount of users and has been trending better in terms of security (e.g. compare IIS 4 to IIS 7). I think the recent attack focus on Adobe Reader lately is somewhat of an acknowledgment that attacking Microsoft products is getting harder. By no means is Microsoft perfect, but they've learned some lessons and are getting better.

Comment: @Jeff Moser So how about that new IE 8 0-day on Windows 7 at pwn2own?  What Microsoft says is meaningless when their software is constantly broken.  All I see is Exploit after Exploit,  absolutely nothing has changed.

Comment: @TheRook: Anytime your product is used by hundreds of millions of users, you'll become a target. Security is hard and requires a lot of defense-in-depth strategies. It's a very asymmetric battle where you have to defend against everything and the attacker only needs to find one weakness. Additionally, with such a widespread user community, you have to do a lot of regression testing to verify a fix. It's hard and I commend people like Michael that are honestly trying.

Let's put aside flame war tendencies and address this question fairly by pointing to good practices and help the community.

Comment: @The Rook - Linux has it's own issues too! it's not like the "many eyeballs" mantra actually works!

Comment: @The Rook - actually a lot has changed: the number of vulns over time has dropped in MS software, it'll never be zero vulns. But just as importantly, we're adding defenses that make zero-days harder to exploit. Again, not impossible - but if a defense renders an attack improbable then I call that a victory.

Comment: @Michael It doesn't matter if you are doing "better",  when you are the very first to get owned for every pwn2own.  It doesn't matter how many vulnerabilities you patch when there are **many** 0-Days being sold on the black market (Aurora anyone?).   Firefox/Chrome Vs IE,  There is no contest in terms of secuirty. The linux KERNEL vs the Microsoft KERNEL, there is no contest in terms of secuirty, but in part thats largely because the linux kernel is mature and bugs have been heavily hunted,  where as the Windows kernel is rewritten every few years, and new bugs are introduced.

Comment: Further more any rebuttal you think you have is completely nullified unless you have written more exploits than me (http://milw0rm.com/author/677).  And yes,  I have raped the mighty ActiveX.

Comment: @The Rook - so these bugs in the Linux kernel are not reality? http://secunia.com/advisories/search/?search=linux

I work on Windows - the Windows kernel is not re-written every few years!

Comment: @Michael not all of toughs 9k are kernel bugs, after all the most CVE's issued in a year was 6,514.  I'm happy that to say I have contributed to that number.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, Reading [your book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617228) was a good start. :-)

Responding to your questions:

1. Crypto is a hobby of mine that I sometimes blog about (e.g. on [TLS](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) and [AES](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)). After writing my own implementation of AES, I learned enough to know beyond a reasonable doubt that I should never use my own implementation but rather use the ones written by the CryptoAPI and OpenSSL guys.
2. - [Code reviews](http://smartbear.com/codecollab.php) where people that are good at security issues are marked as required.
   - Having a class on-site with labs to raise awareness of issues mentioned in your book as well internal mailing lists discussing new issues.
   - Several folks listen to the [Security Now podcast](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) to keep current on what types of issues are out there and what is getting attacked. This indirectly affects design.
3. Except for an on-site course and buying the code review tool, none of these require management approval.

Comment: What's your opinion of security now? I find they use the phrase "better security" enough to make me think Gibson focuses on absolutism rather than risk management.

Comment: I wish it'd go in more depth, but it's easy to listen to on the commute. Steve is a bit more paranoid than I am, but I guess that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an indie mac developer, but also a platform security evangelist: I'm the author of Pro Cocoa Application Security published by Wrox. In that book I champion the secure dev technique I use myself: it's based on the Swiderski and Snyder threat modeling, but with two changes. I make it lighter weight by considering which entry points access which assets without using DFDs. I also put more focus on identifying users and misusers, which I think makes it more applicable to shrinkwrap software.

As far as tool support is concerned, I use the Xcode static analyzer (based on clang), but have found it doesn't detect some common vulnerabilities. I did file bugs though :-). I also always use the gcc _FORTIFY_SOURCE macro. There aren't good Mac risk analysis tools but I'm working on that... ;-)

I've spoken on security to Mac devs at conferences and in podcasts and gotten plenty of feedback, if you want me to clarify anything I've said or are interested in the community feedback please ask in comments. Private questions are welcome to (though I'd prefer to stay on the forum): iamleeg at securemacprogramming dot
com.

Answer (score 0):

We think before we code. Strangely enough, it avoids many bugs, including those which are exploitable by adverse parties and henceforth known as "security holes".

Part of the trick is not letting anyone near a keyboard unless he has a solid amount of experience and expertise.

Comment: More experience isn't always better.  For instance,  dangling pointer attacks are not even 5 years old,  but they are being used to exploit IE under Windows 7.  A senior programmer that knows buffer overflows very well,  will likely miss the new exploitation techniques.

Comment: and that's why defenses are so critically important - you will never get 100% of your code 100% as new exploit techniques are constantly created.